# ¿Se guardan directamente los datos de las variables u objetos inicializados en el metodo constructor en la memoria RAM?

Tags: java, poo

Es decir: Si yo inicializado un objeto "x" en el método constructor, voy a tener rápido acceso a este cuando lo utilice en alguna parte de mi código?
¿Se guarda direcamente en la memoria RAM? O hay una memoria intermedia entre la RAM y la máquina virtual de JAVA? Así como una especie de Caché.

Quiero saber esto a fondo para desidir en que momento debo inicializar una variable u objeto declarado dentro de mi clase. Esto para mejorar el performance de mi aplicación

Comment: revisa lo que es la JVM y como hace la gestion para el manejo de memoria. Te explica como  se almacenan la clases, variables globales y locales ademas de la static. Busca Java heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para efectos de tu aplicación, **si**, al invocar el constructor, se reserva espacio en la *RAM* y se almacena allí esa instancia del objeto.

Para tu programa, este objeto se mantendrá ocupando esa memoria hasta luego de salir de contexto y un poco más de tiempo, cuando el recolector de basura corra de nuevo, y entonces se liberará dicha memoria.

Ahora, es probable que esta instancia no esté realmente todo el tiempo en RAM. Por ejemplo, que el sistema operativo *baje* temporalmente la *página* de memoria dónde reside tu instancia de objeto a disco, si el sistema está limitado de recursos (o no, en el caso de linux). Esta *optimización* se hace como parte del manejo de *memoria virtual* de los sistemas operativos modernos y permite a una máquina exceder su capacidad original de memoria (a costa de una gran pérdida de rendimiento).

Eso si, al momento que tu programa acceda a algún dato contenido dentro del objeto, para leerlo o modificarlo, este será de nuevo colocado en *RAM* de manera *transparente* a tu programa, pues es solo en la *RAM* dónde puede realizarse esta operación.

De hecho, esto es realizado de manera tan transparente que no puedes hacer mayor cosa para impedir que esto ocurra, salvo estar utilizando el objeto todo el tiempo.

Lo que tu programa experimentará en ese caso, es cierto retraso.

Hoy por hoy, en muchas arquitecturas, la JVM interactúa de manera *coordinada* con el sistema operativo de base para que el rendimiento sea aceptable.